# Finding $ {\int e^\sqrt[k]{-a \ln(x)+b} \:dx} $ in terms of special functions

Tags: integration, exponential-function, special-functions

I have come across [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/296136/is-this-a-known-distribution) distribution in my work, and I was wondering if it were possible to represent its integral in some way.

$${\int e^{\sqrt[k]{-a \ln{x}+b} }\:dx}$$

I'm pretty sure there's no closed form solution to this, and attempting to take the Maclaurin series of this and integrating that is tedious to say the least.

Can this integral be expressed in terms of a special function? Even the hypergeometric function will do at a stretch.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding  with infinite sum:

$\int \exp \left((-a \ln (x)+b)^{1/k}\right) \, dx=\int \left(\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }
   \frac{(b-a \ln (x))^{n/k}}{n!}\right) \, dx=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \int \frac{(b-a \ln
   (x))^{n/k}}{n!} \, dx=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{e^{b/a} \Gamma \left(\frac{k+n}{k},\frac{b}{a}-\ln (x)\right) \left(\frac{b}{a}-\ln (x)\right)^{-\frac{n}{k}} (b-a \ln
   (x))^{n/k}}{n!}=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{e^{b/a}
   E_{-\frac{n}{k}}\left(\frac{b}{a}-\ln (x)\right) (b-a \ln (x))^{1+\frac{n}{k}}}{a n!}$

where: $\Gamma \left(\frac{k+n}{k},\frac{b}{a}-\ln (x)\right)$ is  incomplete gamma function,
$E_{-\frac{n}{k}}\left(\frac{b}{a}-\ln (x)\right)$ is [exponential integral function.](http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/ExpIntegralEi/introductions/ExpIntegrals/ShowAll.html)

**Edited:**

only for $k=2$:
$$\int \exp \left(\sqrt{-a \ln (x)+b}\right) \, dx=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{e^{b/a} E_{-\frac{n}{2}}\left(\frac{b}{a}-\ln (x)\right) (b-a \ln (x))^{1+\frac{n}{2}}}{a n!}=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }
   \frac{\left(e^{b/a} (b-a \ln (x))^{1+\frac{n}{2}}\right) \int_1^{\infty } \frac{\exp \left(-t \left(\frac{b}{a}-\ln
   (x)\right)\right)}{t^{-\frac{n}{2}}} \, dt}{a n!}=\int_1^{\infty } \left(\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{\left(e^{b/a} (b-a \ln
   (x))^{1+\frac{n}{2}}\right) \exp \left(-t \left(\frac{b}{a}-\ln (x)\right)\right)}{(a n!) t^{-\frac{n}{2}}}\right) \, dt=\int_1^{\infty }
   \frac{e^{\frac{b}{a}-\frac{b t}{a}+\sqrt{t} \sqrt{b-a \ln (x)}} x^t (b-a \log (x))}{a} \, dt=e^{\sqrt{b-a \ln (x)}} x+\frac{e^{\frac{b}{a}+\frac{a b}{4 b-4 a \ln (x)}} \sqrt{\pi }
   x^{\frac{a^2}{-4 b+4 a \ln (x)}} \sqrt{b-a \ln (x)}}{2 \sqrt{\frac{b}{a}-\ln (x)}}+\frac{e^{\frac{b}{a}+\frac{a b}{4 b-4 a \ln (x)}} \sqrt{\pi
   } x^{\frac{a^2}{-4 b+4 a \ln (x)}} \text{erf}\left(\frac{-\frac{2 b}{a}+2 \ln (x)+\sqrt{b-a \ln (x)}}{2 \sqrt{\frac{b}{a}-\ln (x)}}\right)
   \sqrt{b-a \ln (x)}}{2 \sqrt{\frac{b}{a}-\ln (x)}}$$

Comment: The exponential integral function you use is this one, right?

$E_{-\frac{n}{k}}\left(x\right) = \int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{{e^{-tx}}}{t^\frac{-n}{k}} dt$

It's not clear to me how you arrived at it in your last step.

Comment: @Ingolifs.For all calculation I'm use Mathematica.

Answer (score 0):

Try plugging the exponent into the maclaurin series for the exponential function and integrating term by term.

Comment: For an infinite number of integrations?